# Delete tables by regex

Tags: regex, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way of deleting multiple tables using a regex in SparkSQL?

I would like to do something like this:

```
sqlContext.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS job*")
```

Where `job*` would stand for all tables starting with `job`.

Comment: I'm not familiarized with spark but if it follows sql ansi pattern (which most likely it do) there is no such command. Best you can do is to list all tables based on the information schema (don't know how it is called on spark) and delete one by one in a procedure like instruction